# Error 404 when saving or previewing one specific page

Tags: 404-error, save-post, previews

While the whole site seems working correctly, I have one specific published page that will throw a 404 error when previewing or saving. WP 4.6.1 installed:

Attempts made till now to fix:

- saved permalinks (currently set to Day and name)
- disabled all plugins
- deleted cookies from browser
- checked out WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL) consistency
- reverted to draft (cannot save however gives 404)
- created a new page and imported content

Could it be possible that some server settings are preventing page save/preview on some pages

Comment: This question is WP specific, that is the error occurs under particular circumstances using WP. 
It looks to me that too often on this site censorship is applied from an arbitrary and biased point of view! Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a security setting in the server (Apache). Changed a rule and voilà!

Comment: Hi, @Riccardo! Any chance you can share what the setting was that you changed that fixed the problem?

Comment: Sorry mate, I didn't take a notice at that time and I really can't remember :-(